R8 keeps preventing build due to `lombok.NonNull` annotation
When I attempt to Generate Signed App Bundle / APK... of my perfectly building and running app, I get the following error:
Missing classes detected while running R8. Please add the missing classes or apply additional keep rules that are generated in missing_rules.txt

The file missing_rules.txt only contains the following:
# Please add these rules to your existing keep rules in order to suppress warnings.
# This is generated automatically by the Android Gradle plugin.
-dontwarn lombok.NonNull

But when I add exactly what's specified in missing_rules.txt, I keep getting the same error. This error keeps occurring even when I add to my proguard.cfg the following:
-dontwarn lombok.**
-keepattributes *Annotation*

My build.gradle contains the required:
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.36'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.36'

So why am I still getting this error?
Note: I ran  ..\gradlew dependencies and verified that Lombok appears under compileOnly and annotationProcessor only.
At this point, I am out of ideas. I would appreciate any tip that could help me get past this unexpected hurdle.
My Gradle environment:
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 8.9
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:    2024-07-11 14:37:41 UTC
Revision:      d536ef36a19186ccc596d8817123e5445f30fef8

Kotlin:        1.9.23
Groovy:        3.0.21
Ant:           Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
Launcher JVM:  21.0.3 (JetBrains s.r.o. 21.0.3+-12282718-b509.11)
Daemon JVM:    C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr (no JDK specified, using current Java home)
OS:            Windows 10 10.0 amd64

Android Gradle Plugin Version: 8.7.3

Answering my own question, for the benefit of others who may be baffled by this seemingly mysterious problem:
I solved this problem by simply placing
-dontwarn lombok.NonNull

in the proguard.cfg of the app's module, not the library module.
Explanation: My app is made of an app module and a library module. The library module is the one that actually uses Lombok's NonNull annotation, so I thought that the library's proguard.cfgis the one that should contain the -dontwarn lombok.NonNull directive.
I was wrong: It's the other way around.

An alternative approach would be to add the rules to the library module, and 'export' them to consuming apps by specifying the configuration file with consumerProguardFiles (in library's build config).

I wasn't aware of consumerProguardFiles. It looks like something that could be very useful to me. I will study it. Thank you @AlexLipov for this tip.
